# AppleScript convert variable that is a string into a list

Tags: arrays, string, list, applescript

I am attempting to do a shell script within my AppleScript where I grep a CSV file and it returns a list to my AppleScript.

For example, my CSV has lines

```
01,{"tacos","burritos"}
02,{"burgers","hot dogs", "corn dogs"}
```

my AppleScript is set as

```
set a to 01
set b to 02    
set myMenu to do shell script "grep " & a & " [path to CSV] | cut -d ',' -f 2")
    set menuChoice to (choose from list myMenu)
    display alert menuChoice
```

When I do this, my choose from list displays as one item in the list that shows the menu items as a string, but I want them to be individual menu items.

Meaning my choose from list shows as:

```
{"tacos","burritos"}
```

Instead of:

```
tacos
burritos
```

Comment: You can just use AppleScript, but the result from reading a file or using a shell script will be text, so you will need to convert it to a list.  The easiest way with your example would be to run a script with the result, e.g. `set myMenu to run script myMenu`, but the best way would be to restructure your file so you can just get the items without using the list syntax.

Comment: Agreed: switch from CSV to XML or JSON if you can. Both can describe complex nested data, and are easy to parse using existing AS tools.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following should give you an idea of how to grab multiple items from the output of a shell script to populate an Applescript list. Basically, say your shell script does this:

```
echo item1,item2,item3
```

You can offer those 3 items in a list for the user to choose from like this:

```
osascript <<EOF
   set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ","
   set theList to every text item of (do shell script "echo item1,item2,item3")
   set menuChoice to (choose from list theList)
EOF
```

which will give you this:

[image]

---

Now, more similar to your question, if you make your CSV look like this:

```
01,tacos,burritos
02,burgers,hot dogs,corn dogs
```

You can then use:

```
osascript <<EOF
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ","
set theList to every text item of (do shell script "grep '^01,' my.csv | cut -d, -f 2-")
set menuChoice to (choose from list theList)
EOF
```

to get:

[image]